# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #5](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/5) on English Language Learners has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Void]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/5) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5737608471642112).

Comment: Is the new moderator Void, or is the new moderator void? I think we should be told.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - It looks like we have an answer now.

Comment: This should be closed as a duplicate of the new announcement.

Answer (score 7):

##### Thank you so much! :)

I'm grateful to those who participated in the election and those who elected me as a mod. I'll try my best to make ELL a better place.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think you, Fumble, Bassford, Java, David, and many others who've been here for a long time should really think about running for mod next time ...

Comment: @AIQ - I have been a moderator at another site (not one of the SE ones). Never again.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Could you give us some reasons?

Answer (score 3):

Some of you have asked about what happened after the recent election results were announced on Tuesday, November 2nd, 2021. There's not a huge amount of detail that we can go into here without revealing private information or conversations. Our policies have always followed the concept that moderation actions should generally happen in closed spaces that give people the freedom to speak without risking their transgressions being made public.

What I can say is that it became clear to us that there were concerns about Void's early participation on this site and we reached out to them to discuss. As part of that, Void chose to step down as a moderator. As such, we are announcing the runner-up as the winner of the election - which will be in a separate post.

Trust is a very important part of moderation and we - and I hope you - want to know that your moderator team can be trusted to act in accordance of the expectations of this platform. We appreciate that Void was willing to admit to their mistakes and opted to step down. We also strongly believe that people can change and we give great latitude to those who learn from their mistakes and grow into valued members of the community - and we hope that Void follows this path.

I sincerely apologise for the confusion that the actions here have caused - our delay in coming to you was so that we could work with Void and the other mods to determine the next steps before we acted. Thank you for your patience. While I'm not able to answer much in the specific, please let me know if you have any questions I can address.

Comment: There are quite a few well-respected community members that started their participation on ELL with serious missteps that required moderator intervention. It's unfortunate that Void didn't benefit from the private intervention that the other community members got, and I hope that everyone will accept the issue as resolved and recognize that doing the right thing in this situation wasn't easy for Void.

Comment: @ColleenV - For me the bigger issue is why, despite red flags being raised repeatedly with the moderation team in private this was allowed *to happen in the first place*. It's not like they can say "oops, we didn't know".

Comment: @Richard Well, ELL had only two very active moderators for a period of time, and one of them is moderating six other sites. I appreciate them stepping up and taking on the responsibilities during trying times, but "red flag" type incidents with no hard evidence really need someone who is more focused. Also, the person raising those red flags did it in a way that caused moderation problems for already overburdened moderators instead of following the process. Hindsight is 20/20, so I don't want to do too much armchair quarterbacking. I think adding gotube to the team will resolve most of issue.

Comment: @Richard You're making some assumptions there that just are wholly incorrect. While people can have concerns and raise red flags, we can only act on provable, supported information. We don't generally act on hunches or conjectures.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the apparent early transgressions, but: "We also strongly believe that people can change and we give great latitude to those who learn from their mistakes and grow into valued members of the community - and we hope that Void follows this path." - To the best of my knowledge this has already happened in Void's case and I for one therefore hope Void will continue to contribute.

Comment: I've cleaned up comments under this because they're crossing a line. We do not talk about sanctions publicly. That has always been our line, it's not going to change now. For everyone prodding and probing, please, stop. These conjectures and wild guesses are not helping - CMs were aware, involved, and looked into it. That's all I can say. Stop trying to "assign blame", please. The Moderators did fine.

Comment: AIQ, What you're saying is neither truth nor kindness. It's your interpretation based on half of the information and it is inappropriate for this space.